# How I can write a single function to work with different types

Tags: reflection, go

Given the following example, is it anyhow possible to create a function that can literally reproduce (not only get the reflect.Type) the actual type for further manipulation? I know go is statically typed and although it's very cool that I can pass any struct to a function that defines an interface parameter, is there any chance I can do more the other way around?

I already looked into the reflect package but only found stuff that returned a reflect.Type or reflect.Value. I used the New() method which returned a new reflect.Value - and there I couldn't set any fields. Maybe someone experienced with the reflect package can tell me if this is definitely possible or not - or if there's another way to do it.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type User struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    user := User{Name:"FooBar"}
    DoSomethingGenericWithStruct(user)
}

func DoSomethingGenericWithStruct(i interface{}) {
    // access fields of i ...
    // or create slice of type of i ([]User) ...
    // or instantiate new object of type of i (new User) ...
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Golang is famously lacking parametric types and generic functions. You might look at https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/go-linq or even http://bouk.co/blog/idiomatic-generics-in-go/ for inspiration.

Comment: For what reason has this question been downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to pass a pointer to your struct to be able to modify it.

Also keep in mind that using reflection has a high runtime performance cost.

```
func DoSomethingGenericWithStruct(i interface{}) {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    if val.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        panic("need a pointer")
    }
    val = val.Elem() // now you can modify it
    // add error checking and such, this will panic if it's not a struct or there's no "Name" field
    val.FieldByName("Name").SetString("stuff")
}
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/hFCltl3xLx)</kbd>

To create a new element and assign it:

```
val = val.Elem()
nval := reflect.New(val.Type()).Elem() // create a new struct of the same type
nval.FieldByName("Name").SetString("stuff") 
val.Set(nval)
```

to modify the actual struct, not `reflect.Value`, you will have to get the `interface{}` to it then assert it to your type, for example:

```
nval := reflect.New(val.Type()).Elem() // create a new struct of the same type
user := nval.Interface().(User)
user.Name = "Stuff"
val.Set(reflect.ValueOf(user))
```

Comment: So basically I will never get a true User object but rather always a reflection object? Like I will never be able to do `nval.Name = "stuff"`?

Comment: @skripted you can, I added another example.

Comment: awesome, thank you! so I really need to know the type beforehand and type assert it, damned. too sad there's no way to do `user := nval.Interface().( reflect.TypeOf(i) )`

Comment: @skripted you might want to reconsider what you're trying to do or if Go is the tool for your project if you really need that functionality.

Comment: I think Go is the right tool, I just might be using the wrong features for the wrong problems. I guess I will reconsider how my application works.